# How to deal with facebook accounts connected to an app that are being converted to a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Facebook offers a mechanism to convert a personal profile into a fan page. I am currently dealing with a user who had her personal profile connected to our Facebook app. She then did the conversion and now can no longer access her profile in the app.

From what I can see, it appears that the ID of her old personal account does no longer exist in Facebook. The converted fan page has a new ID. She cannot access the app with the page identity (which is a general restriction for pages, I think). She then created a new personal profile but that of course has a new ID as well.

So I am facing the situation that there are two entries in the database, one with the old deleted ID and one with the new account ID. I can merge these two app profiles manually and make them use the ID of the new personal account.

But I would like to handle this problem automatically and transparently to the user or at least in a way they can do the merge themselves. It seems to be difficult since the old account is already destroyed and I do not have any way to associate the new personal account with the existing app profile.

Do you know of a good way to deal with this problem? The only way I can see is to have people generate an authorization link before doing the conversion and later on use it to do the merge. But i guess most often they would do it the other way round and end up with a broken profile.

Comment: What you're describing shouldn't be the case - when a user is converted from a profile to a page, they retain a username and password they can log into which provides access to manage that page - the username and password are for an account which should have the same ID as the original profile - unless your user deactivated that account after setting up their new profile or something, it should be transparent to your side (except that the user won't have a name, friends, feed, etc when you fetch their details via the API)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - i'll try to get more details how the conversion was actually done. When logging in with the credentials provided during conversion, does the user get access to a full private profile or is this just some limited account?

Comment: it's a limited account with the same user ID, username and password they had before - a new page gets created which they're made an admin of via that account - if the user setup a new profile for themselves that's separate, but their original login details should still work for managing their apps and pages but not for other Facebook functionality - use of the API should be fine, but your app might not support such accounts due to them not having the same data available as a regular profile (e.g. no 'name' field)